# What models are involved in the OpenERP Point of Sale Application?

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I am on Odoo 9. The debug options for the Point of Sale application are different to the usual ones for other modules. They do not let me see the models and views involved in the application. Could someone give me some basic guidance as to the architecture of this application. For instance, when the payment button is pressed, what method is called, and to which model does this method belong?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the POS generates sale.order records.

You can confirm this by creating an Order in the POS and then looking it up in the backend.